# opengl instanced drawing - 3D Arrows

Tags: c++, opengl

I have to draw millions of arrows. The information I have is as below.

- location of each arrow
- direction of each arrow (vector direction)
- length if each arrow

With this information, can I use opengl instanced drawing to draw arrows.

I have gone through the instanced examples. In all those examples, they have explained matrix transformations for each instance etc... .

But, I am not clear, with the above data, whether it is possible to do or not.

Comment: You could. But why would you want to? It sounds to me like you would have to generate new vertices/primitives for each arrow, depending on how you want to render arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the arrow is a vector, you can just insert all your vector data into a uniform array** and use gl_InstanceID to look them up in your vertex shader and simply pass them over to gl_Position.

If you need to apply a transformation to the arrows (by looking at your data: translation for the location, rotation for the direction and scaling for the length), you would issue the instanced drawing statement on a single set of vertices (your base arrow), use a uniform array of matrices for the transformation and look those matrices up in a similar way in your vertex shader.

**Depending on how many instances you have though,the data may not fit into a uniform array. So you can look into using a Uniform block (which allows you to store more data than a simple uniform variable) and if that is also not enough, a GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER will do the trick. 
Don't let the name fool you, GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER can hold arbitrary data, not just texture data.

Uniform block is backed by https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object

For texture buffer, read out https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture